# Нагрузочное тестирование Web-сервера по HTTPS на основе алгоритмов ГОСТ

Tags: яндекс-танк

Стоит задача провести нагрузочное тестирование Web-сервера по HTTPS который настроен на работу по алгоритмам ГОСТ. На сервере с танком `openssl ciphers` выдает список в котором есть ГОСТы. Запустил нагрузочный тест и в перехваченном трафике видно что не проходит Handshake: в сообщении `Client Hello` в списке `Cipher suites` отсуствую ГОСТы. При выполнении команды `openssl s_client -connect ipserver:port -key gosrPrivate.pem -cert gostCert.pem -msg` с сервера с танком GET запрос выполняется успешно. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Впилили поддержку клиентских ciphers и сертификатов

- https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank/pull/174
- https://github.com/yandex-load/phantom/pull/1

попробуйте поставить фантом и танк из репозиториев?

Comment: если gost engine подключен конфигом /etc/ssl/openssl.conf, phantom его игнорирует. Т.е нужно что-то вроде этого:

    
    r2d2@ubuntu:~/phantom$ git diff pd/ssl/ssl.C -U1
    diff --git a/pd/ssl/ssl.C b/pd/ssl/ssl.C
    index a0c9774..77c8c47 100644
    --- a/pd/ssl/ssl.C
    +++ b/pd/ssl/ssl.C
    @@ -17,6 +17,7 @@
     #include <openssl/engine.h>
    +#include <openssl/conf.h>
    
    
    @@ -48,6 +49,7 @@ struct mgr_t {
            inline mgr_t() throw() {
    +              OPENSSL_config(NULL);
                    SSL_library_init();
    r2d2@ubuntu:~/phantom$